# jq "Invalid numeric literal" error with valid JSON data

Tags: jq

The data

```
{    
  "asdf":   "1.0",
  "jkadfsjkl": "xxx"
}
```

passes JSONLint but jqplay.org and jq v1.5 return

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 9
```

Comment: `jq .` on this gives no error. What's your actual `jq` command? (Ditto for `.` on jqplay.org.)

Comment: I cut-n-paste from what I posted to jqplay and it works.  I cut-n-paste from Notepad++ which has the exact same thing, to jqplay, and it fails.  Notepad++ shows no hidden characters other than CR-LF.

Comment: If you copy-and-paste directly from your question into the system where you're running `jq`, do you still have a problem?

Comment: Just looked again in Notepad++.  I had 'show all characters' checked which showed the CR-LFs.  I noticed that only SOME of the spaces had the single pixel representing a space.  I deleted the spaces with a pixel and replaced them with spaces that displayed as a pixel.  It now works.  Now the question is what character appears as a space but is not a space?

Comment: Our client sent us a file full of unicode spaces.  Joy.

Comment: Not reproducible or caused by a typo. Voting to close …

Answer (score 0):

There are extra spaces in this line: `"asdf":   "1.0",` .. I wonder if there might be an invalid character in there.